# Pantheon Site to Local Environment

Tags: 7, backups

I have recently inherited a Drupal 7 site running on [Pantheon.io](https://pantheon.io)
I have set up a local Drupal 7 server for a dev/test environment that is working flawlessly as a fresh install.
However, once I put the code, files, and database backups in place, my content appears, but there is no theme or CSS present, none of my links work, etc.

I have a feeling there is a simple fix for this, but I have exhausted my limited knowledge of this platform.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What is your actual question as I can't find one in the text you posted. `(-:`

Comment: @leymannx - When I bring my database, code, and files from Pantheon to my local environment, my theme/css doesn't appear to work. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone the code
2. Import database
3. Configure your settings.php file
4. Get public files; copy them to sites/default/files
5. Compile CSS and JavaScript in the theme, if it is required
6. Clear the cache

Those step should works.

If [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module installed in [Pantheon.io](https://pantheon.io/)
you can get the database and public files from https://pantheon.io/admin/config/system/backup_migrate.

Comment: #4 - copy them to `sites/all/default/files` - under `sites` i can go to `all` **OR** `default`, I don't have an `/all/default` path.

Comment: Sorry it's `sites/default/files`.  i edit my answer.

Comment: Your suggestion "Compile CSS and JavaScript in the theme, if it is required" was my key... configured the `settings.php` so that 'preprocess_css` and `preprocess_js` were set to `0` and now my main page looks fantastic!!!  Now, all of my links are "not found," including the `/user` login path. Suggestions?

Comment: check with `yousite.com/?q=user` instead of `yousite.com/user`  if it works ?

Comment: `/?q=user` does work :)  I don't know what configuration change to make to fix the rest.

Comment: Enable Clean url from `admin/config/search/clean-urls`

Comment: Phenomenal, thank you! I was able to disable Clean-URLs, fix the server config issue, then enable clean-urls. From my testing so far, it seems as if everything else is in working order. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm glad that help!